# My query is slow on SQL Server according where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with 1 millions rows.

**Case 1**: `Where` clause with 'cvaleur'

```
SELECT TOP(2000)  
    [p].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] AS [id], 
    [v].[Date_MAJ] AS [DateMaj], 
    [v].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable_Valeur] AS [IdPaieParamConstanteVariableValeur]
FROM 
    [Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN 
    [Paie_Theme] AS [t] ON [p].[Code_Paie_Theme] = [t].[Code_Paie_Theme]
INNER JOIN 
    [Paie_Param_Constante_Variable_Valeur] AS [v] ON [p].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] = [v].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable]
WHERE 
    [p].[Code_Constante_Variable_Type] = N'cvaleur'
ORDER BY 
    [DateMaj] DESC
```

This query returns my rows in 200 ms

**Case 2:** `Where` clause with 'vformule'

```
SELECT TOP(2000) 
    [p].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] AS [id], 
    [v].[Date_MAJ] AS [DateMaj], 
    [v].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable_Valeur] AS [IdPaieParamConstanteVariableValeur]
FROM 
    [Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN 
    [Paie_Theme] AS [t] ON [p].[Code_Paie_Theme] = [t].[Code_Paie_Theme]
INNER JOIN 
    [Paie_Param_Constante_Variable_Valeur] AS [v] ON [p].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] = [v].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable]
WHERE 
    [p].[Code_Constante_Variable_Type] = N'vformule'
ORDER BY 
    [DateMaj] DESC
```

This query returns my rows in 5 secondes! Why?

I have two indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Relationship9] 
ON [dbo].[Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] ([Code_Constante_Variable_Type] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
                ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [DateMAJ] 
ON [dbo].[Paie_Param_Constante_Variable_Valeur] ([Date_MAJ] DESC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
                ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Case 3:** `Where` clause with 'vformule' but order by ASC

```
SELECT TOP(2000) 
    [p].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] AS [id], 
    [v].[Date_MAJ] AS [DateMaj], 
    [v].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable_Valeur] AS [IdPaieParamConstanteVariableValeur]
FROM 
    [Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN 
    [Paie_Theme] AS [t] ON [p].[Code_Paie_Theme] = [t].[Code_Paie_Theme]
INNER JOIN 
    [Paie_Param_Constante_Variable_Valeur] AS [v] ON [p].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable] = [v].[Id_Paie_Param_Constante_Variable]
WHERE 
    [p].[Code_Constante_Variable_Type] = N'vformule'
ORDER BY 
    [DateMaj] ASC
```

This query returns my rows in 200ms!

My index on DateMAJ is DESC.

I need to order my SQL on descending...

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Have you looked at the **actual execution plans** for each of those queries? Please post the table structure here, and the execution plans at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Do you run the queries multiple times and get the same result? Sometime one query is executed very fast at this time but not at that time.

Comment: Below the execution plans for the case :

**Case 1 :** [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJPm_1zgS) 

**Case 2 :** [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy5sNyMlB) 

**Case 3 :** [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1sddkzxS)

Answer (score 0):

I have two initial thoughts:

1) Index [Code_Constante_Variable_Type] is sorted ASC, and thus the earlier value ("cvaleur") is found sooner than the later value ("vformule").

2) The number of occurrences in the table for value "cvaleur" is lower than the number of occurrences in the table for value "vformule".

Comment: I have the same occurrences for "vformule" and "cvaleur".

Comment: I have renamed "vformule" into "caformule" but anything has changed.

Comment: Interesting that the execution plans were all identical with identical subtree costs.  What happens in case 1 and case 2 if you remove TOP(2000)?

Comment: If I remove TOP(2000) my queries returns my 1 millions rows in 6 secondes. It's the same thing...

Comment: But both queries take 6 seconds without TOP?  Vs with TOP the 1st query takes 200ms and the 2nd query takes 5-6 seconds?

Comment: I just noticed that you only included "estimated" execution plans - can you please update your images with the "actual" plans after you run each query? (both with the top 2000, sorted desc)

Comment: I have tested other things. I have deleted all rows with 'cvaleur' and I have inserted them again. Now the query with 'vformule' take 200ms and 'cvaleur' take 5s. it seems that it's the last rows that are slow...

See below actual plan :
**Case 1: (now 5 s)**   [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1Cf18mlS)
**Case 2: (now 200ms)**  [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BywwyI7eS)

Comment: Look at the index scan and key lookup operators in Case 1 - all 1m+ rows are being read, vs Case 2 where only 2000 rows are read.  This also causes Case 1 to perform the index seek 1m+ times vs Case 2 2000 times.  There's definitely something up with your index(es) and/or data.  Do you have manual statistics on these indexes?  Are they fragmented?  What fields are in the clustered index?

Comment: Also, try running both queries with OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end of each query, just to eliminate parameter sniffing as a potential cause.

Comment: Hi, I've found the solution with this link : [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188704/why-is-select-faster-than-select-top-500-in-sql-server)